# How to perform series of operations on a region of a NumPy array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of the following structure which I'll refer to as x:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

What I wish to do is perform a series of equations on this array but only on a specific section of the array every single time and keep the array structured the same.

I am aware of using np.where to locate values based on a condition such as:

`loc = np.where(x >4)`

Now performing the above returns:

`(array([1, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([3, 2, 3], dtype=int64))`

But using `x[loc]` returns the raw values which whilst expected is not what I'm looking for as it will only returns those values not the whole array.

So my desired output is to have the initial array x same as above:

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
```

From that perform a series of operations for values which satisfy a given condition and also keeps the array intact so for a given equation like so:

`5*x+1`

Will only be performed on values greater than 5 (`x>5`) and keep the array in the same structure so it will result in.

```
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  26
3  4  26 31
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Use a `mask` : `x >4` an use it to assign and the masked values for computing new values?

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to use that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) shown as a sample case -

1) Setup sample input :

```
In [373]: np.random.seed(0)

In [374]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,4))

In [375]: a
Out[375]: 
array([[5, 0, 3, 3],
       [7, 3, 5, 2],
       [4, 7, 6, 8]])
```

2) Get the mask :

```
In [376]: mask = a>4

In [377]: mask
Out[377]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

3) Get masked values :

```
In [378]: a_masked = a[mask]
```

4) Update the masked places with computations on the masked values :

```
In [380]: a[mask] = 5*a_masked + 1

In [381]: a
Out[381]: 
array([[26,  0,  3,  3],
       [36,  3, 26,  2],
       [ 4, 36, 31, 41]])
```

5) For more operations, get the masked values again and repeat -

```
In [382]: a_masked = a[mask]

In [383]: a[mask] = a_masked + 100

In [384]: a
Out[384]: 
array([[126,   0,   3,   3],
       [136,   3, 126,   2],
       [  4, 136, 131, 141]])
```

Alernative to `4` and `5` : If you don't want to update `a` after each operation, we can update the array of masked values and write-back to the input array at the very end. Thus, steps `4` and `5` would be replaced, as shown below -

```
In [386]: a # Input array
Out[386]: 
array([[5, 0, 3, 3],
       [7, 3, 5, 2],
       [4, 7, 6, 8]])

In [387]: a_masked = a[mask]

In [388]: a_masked = 5*a_masked + 1 # operation #1

In [389]: a_masked = a_masked + 100 # operation #2

In [390]: a[mask] = a_masked        # write back to input array

In [391]: a
Out[391]: 
array([[126,   0,   3,   3],
       [136,   3, 126,   2],
       [  4, 136, 131, 141]])
```